# How to uninstall apps in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, steam, software-uninstall

I know it would seem like a simple task. I've tried right-clicking apps, (lets use steam as an example) and clicking uninstall. However, they do not uninstall. So far, i noticed this happening with Steam and Virtualbox. I've even tried a third-party program (i forget the name, I had re-installed Ubuntu) Please help, I want to be able to uninstall stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall from the Software Centre - navigate to the page of the app you want to uninstall. At the top right, there will be a "Remove" button.

Alternately, you could use the terminal and use

```
sudo apt-get remove <app_name>
```

Comment: Well, `apt-get autoremove is to remove automatically all unused packages`. Should be `sudo apt-get remove app_name`